# Is it possible to detect css pseudo element using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, responsive-design

In my responsive WordPress theme using Twitter Bootstrap, I'm trying to use a technique similar to [CSS Conditional loading](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ConditionalCSS/) but relying on PHP instead of Javascript minimize from so many requests loading.

What I'd like to do is use PHP to detect the `:after` pseudo element content property to see which element is loading based upon the media query/viewport size of the browser.

Here's example CSS:

```
    body:after { 
        display: none; 

        /* Default */
        content: "A";
    }

    @media (min-width: 35em) {
        body:after {
            content: "B";
        }
    }
```

To be very specific, if PHP can detect that `content: "A"` is active, it will load `custom_mobile_content()` hook which renders mobile content. If it detects `content: "B"`, it will load `custom_desktop_content()` hook which renders more desktop content.

I tried using the javascript version but it requires I put a large block of formatted HTML into a javascript variable and upon rendering of the page there's a huge block of text that's inactive and unused on the page contained within the javascript. PHP seems to be a better fit.

Is there code which can produce this easily?

---

EDIT: It appears that I'd have to pass a JS variable or function to PHP in order for this to work, and I suppose that's pretty complicated.

Here's the javascript I'm trying to work with:

```
$(function() {
    var currentSize = "A";
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');

        /* Ridiculous thing to deal with inconsistent returning of
        value from query. Some browsers have quotes some don't */
        size = size.replace(/"/g, "");
        size = size.replace(/'/g, "");

        if (size != currentSize) {
            if (size == 'B') {
               $(".content").load('<?php custom_hook(); ?>');
               currentSize = 'B';
            }
        }

    }).resize();

}
```

I've included the above code in the WordPress page itself because it doesn't need to be cached in a file. It is only used once and on this page. However, the problem with this is that the `custom_hook()` code is rendered on the page and that hook includes a bunch of markup. If the javascript determines that I'm using `A`, all that markup is on the page in the source code for no reason. I want to find a way to prevent the custom hook from rendering UNLESS it's being used in `B`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please take a look at the [faq] as generic PHP questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Oh, I thought that since this had to do specifically with the WordPress architecture and custom hooks that it applied better here than in stackoverflow. That's why I came here.

Comment: No: [tag:php] works *server-side*, there *is* no [tag:css] applied until *after* the HTML has been produced and sent to the browser. And pseudo-element support isn't (sadly) guaranteed once it gets to the browser.

Comment: To do this you'd essentially need to evaluate the CSS exactly as the browser would, applying all the rules in all the right ways. That's really non-trivial. And especially since you can't be sure how the browser will evaluate it (what *is* the screen width?), this doesn't seem like the best direction to go if it's not critical.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there's no reliable way to detect pseudo-elements, even in JavaScript. They have no CSS Object Model (CSSOM). PHP can't help you in this situation either because it acts only server-side.

For an alternate workflow, you can use JavaScript to find out which media query is currently active. Based on this you can load other resources if necessary.

See this [article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_media_queries_from_code?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_media_queries_from_code) for details on how to work with media queries from JavaScript.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. If you look at the source code in the first link I provided, you'll see how the javascript is used to detect the pseudo element value. As explained here, http://adactio.com/journal/5429/ I need a way to detect whether media queries have been executed in CSS without duplicating the breakpoints. Your link to matchmedia is doing exactly that, duplication. Anyway, if I can find a way to take a block of code, meaning several headings, divs and paragraphs which contain custom hooks, and render that block at the certain break points, then this will work.

Comment: I've edited my problem above to include my thoughts and what problem I'm trying to solve. I appreciate your feedback! :)

Comment: @micah: There's a subtle difference between reading a computed CSS style, and trying to inspect an actual pseudo-element ;)

Comment: @BoltClock I'm still mostly a novice at scripting so I'm sorry if I didn't properly express what I'm trying to do!